# What could be the cause of 504 error for restful api GET request?

Tags: java, apache, rest, jdbc, jboss

I have a RESTful webservices deployed as war on jboss AS which is hosted on apache web server.
Sometimes I am getting 504 error for GET request of api, where it fetches data from mysql DB hosted on AWS.
On restarting jboss server, it gets resolved.
So what could be the issue with, is it database  timeout/connection pool  issue or issue with the server?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could wire up another GET request that just answers with a small test message, and no DB to test if the API is receiving requests and responding correctly, if so it may be the DB connection. Also if you have logs of either or both that would be helpful to see which one timed out

Comment: Get requests without DB connections are working fine. But if it is DB issue then it should throw connection timeout or DB specific exception which is not the case. Only 504 errors are printed in logs.